# How to get selected data from different table in Django database and return json to web client

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views, renderer

I have Company, product, customer table in view.py, and product.id, customer.id are forighen key in Company class, how to get the selected data.

like sql (select * from Company, customer, product where Company.customer_id = customer.id and company.product_id =product.id)
and make it return json, so that in the client side can get the json data?

and how to use the json data in the web client?

Im new in Django, can you help me with this issue?

```
class Company(models.Model):
id = models.IntegerField(blank=True, primary_key=True)
customer_id = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
product_id = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)

class product(models.Model):
id = models.IntegerField(blank=True, primary_key=True)
name = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)

class customer(models.Model):
id = models.IntegerField(blank=True, primary_key=True)
name = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly your models should be in your django application's models.py file. In Django the Foreign Key field is referenced using  `models.ForeignKey` which is documented here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey

You also need to decide which model will reference which foreign key. Like a company can have many customers and products, so the company will be a foreign key in product and customer models.

After that in your views when you fetch details of the customer you will use a code like this

```
company = Company.objects.filter(id=1).select_related('customer')
```

The documentation for select related is given here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#select-related

Then the next step will be to serialize your `company` queryset into json
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/serialization/#serialization-formats-json

Comment: Hi Shahzeb Qureshi, the is the code add in the view.py?company = Company.objects.filter(id=1).select_related('customer')

Comment: and do you have idea how could i get the json data from web client? like get the json data in 127.0.0.1:8000/static/list.html

Comment: Yes your views.py will have a function which will contain the Company queryset code and other code in it. Your urls.py will have a url defined to point too the function in views.py. Your function will return json data and you can call it in your html file using ajax

Comment: It is working! 
@action(detail=True, method=["GET"])
    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = Notification.objects.filter(name=self.request.user).select_related('product_id')
        return queryset